# Get error message with custom validation Class on Tastypie

Tags: python, django, validation, tastypie

I'm trying to get the error message for a field using a custom validation class on tastypie.

I used the code on Tastipye Documentation website (AwesomeValidation class) :  http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validation.html#implementing-your-own-validation

Here's my ressource class :

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):                                                                                                                                             
class Meta:                                                                                                                                                                
    queryset = User.objects.all()                                                                                                                                          
    resource_name = 'user'                                                                                                                                                 
    authorization = Authorization()                                                                                                                                        
    validation = AwesomeValidation()
```

I use slumber to try a POST request :

```
import slumber
api = slumber.API("127.0.0.1", auth=("auth", "auth"))
api.user.post({"username": "test", "password": "test", "password_confirm": "test", "email": "test@example.com"})
```

I get an Error 400, but no error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/slumber/__init__.py", line 125, in post
    resp = self._request("POST", data=s.dumps(data), params=kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/slumber/__init__.py", line 104, in _request
    raise exceptions.HttpClientError("Client Error %s: %s" % (resp.status_code, url), response=resp, content=resp.content)
slumber.exceptions.HttpClientError: Client Error 400: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/
```

Is there anything to do with the custom validation class to get the error message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoth your link:

> Under this validation, every field that’s a string is checked for the
>   word ‘awesome’. If it’s not in the string, it’s an error.

Comment: Yes but i try to get the message : "NOT ENOUGH AWESOME. NEEDS MORE."

Comment: I'm not sure `slumber` will show it to you like this. Try catching the exception and printing `the_exception.content` or just test it with `curl`.

Comment: Thank's ! i didn't know this slumber's limitation. It works perfectly with curl.